# Difference between "fuzz testing" and "monkey test"

Tags: testing, fuzz-testing, monkey-testing

I have recently been thinking of the difference between fuzz testing and monkey test. According to wiki, it seems monkey test is "only" a unit test and fuzz test isn't. Android has [UI/Application Exerciser monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) and it doesn't seems like unit test.

Is there any difference between these testing methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UI/Application Exerciser Monkey is a *fuzz testing* tool. The name is probably related to the fact that it behaves as if a *monkey* uses your application. It might be also related to the fact that (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing#History)):

> "The Monkey" was a Macintosh application developed by Steve Capps
>   prior to 1983. It used journaling hooks to feed random events into Mac
>   programs, and was used to test for bugs in MacPaint.

The bottom line is that *Monkey test* and *Fuzz testing* are different names for essentially the same thing. However, there might be one subtle difference: while *Fuzz testing* is more about using random **data**, *Monkey testing* is about random **actions**.